# How to make non limits lighting system

Tags: c++, c, directx, game-engine, hlsl

i am writing a game engine with directx 11.
I want to creating a lighting system, but, non light limits!

I sending this structure to my pixel shader:

```
struct LightingConstantBufferData {
    DirectionalLight directionalLights[???];
};
```

Problem is 'directionalLights' number of array. C++ required const. But non limits lighting for dynamic array required. I am not know make this.
And my pixel shader code getting part:

```
cbuffer LightingConstantBufferData: register(b3) {
    DirectionalLight directionalLights[SH_TOTAL_LIGHTS]; // 'SH_TOTAL_LIGHTS' is defined from cpp code(shader macro)
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I come from OpenGL, so I may be wrong here, but as far as I know, you can send compute shaders a buffer of data, where the last element of the buffer can be an array of an unknown size, I'm not sure if this is the way in DirectX, but definetly worth a try, if you can do your calculation somehow in a compute shader.

Comment: IMHO this should be a comment, not an answer. If you cannot answer the question with absolute facts and exact knowledge, then don't post an answer. This "answer" is just a guess + some handwaving as far as I can tell.

Comment: Sry for that, but at least it somewhat backed up with knowledge from another API, and since both use the GPU, and try to match the underlying platform, the two shouldn't be too different. As far as I'm aware, it's the same in Vulkan, adding more to my point.

Answer (score 0):

Each 'pass' of rendering is going to be limited to a certain number of lights. Generally graphics shaders and constant buffers are not designed for dynamic arrays.

There are of course other approaches to achieve the effect of 'as many lights as you'd like'.  Multi-pass rendering was the common approach in the old days where you'd render the same frame multiple times and blend the results together. Many engines used a mix of a few 'important' direct lights (3 or 4) for dynamic characters and objects, and static lightmaps for background.

Many modern game engines use 'deferred rendering' or a hybrid of deferred and forward techniques (called forward tiled rendering or "forward+") largely because it allows them to linearly scale lighting based on the desires of designers and artists.

A quick search of the Internet will bring up numerous articles on these topics. This one is a good overview.

[Forward vs Deferred vs Forward+ Rendering with DirectX 11](https://www.3dgep.com/forward-plus/)

> My advice is start small and don't worry about hundreds of lights just yet...  The [DirectX Tool Kit](https://github.com/microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/Getting-Started) may be of use to you as well.

Comment: "Forward+" is one of the worst terms in history, and it's not "a hybrid of deferred and forward rendering". "Forward+" is a marketing term for "Forward tiled shading", but might also be used for "Forward clustered shading". Tiled shading (and it's successor clustered shading) can be implemented for both forward and deferred rendering, these are different things that are not dependend on each other.

Comment: Also, the performance cost of lighting always scales approx. linearly with the number of lights. The thing with tiled/clustered shading is just that the scaling is very small - there's only a small difference between having one or 1000 light sources on screen with these algorithms. The new (ray tracing-based) ReSTIR algorithm from NVidia even manages to render 3 million light sources with smooth shadows in "real time" (~20 FPS on a RTX 2080 Ti)

Comment: I was attempting to provide an overview answer, not a detailed treatise. Still, I edited the "forward+" section per your feedback to be more technically correct. Real-time Raytracing is of course the 'next new thing' but the hardware market penetration for doing it for entire scenes is still not there. Plus 20 FPS may meet the academic definitions of 'real-time' (anything > 10 fps) but it's a long way from the frame-rate needed for interactive games.